# In magento 1.9 how can i show unit price of product in cart & checkout excluding tax?

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento 1.9 how can i show unit price of product in cart & checkout excluding tax?

In cart

**Price of product (without tax) + Tax (seperately) = grand total.**

currently in my cart price contains tax.

Any help will be appreciable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unit price in cart** was achieved by adding these in app/design/frontend//default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
if($customergroup == "RDH")
                          {
                            echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getPrice() + $myDeviceId + $myDeviceId1);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition() + $myDeviceId + $myDeviceId1);
                      }
```